# A-frame-react : how to pass the value when .map()?

Tags: reactjs, aframe, aframe-react

I would like an Entity to spawn for each item added dynamically in the array.

Is it possible to do like this? How would I attribute the value of each item to each Entity ?

```
this.state = {
    items: []
}
```

then in the render :

```
    <Scene>
      {this.state.items.map((item, key) => {
        return (
            <Entity />
         )
        }
       )}
     </Scene>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map over the `items` in your component state and give the `item` string to the `text` prop of the `Entity` component.

**Example**

```
class VRScene extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: ["lemon", "orange"]
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(prevState => {
        return { items: [...prevState.items, Math.random()] };
      });
    }, 2000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Scene>
        {this.state.items.map((item, index) => (
          <Entity
            key={item}
            text={{ value: item, align: "center" }}
            position={{ x: 0, y: 2 - index * 0.1, z: -1 }}
          />
        ))}
      </Scene>
    );
  }
}
```